# My questions are wrongly closed and I am not allowed to ask questions, even before my questions were answered

Tags: support, closed-questions, close-reasons

I have a question about my English Language & Usage Stack Exchange post: [If an apple is bad and there are 5 apples (of the same type of the apple mentioned before) that are bad, then which of the below sentences is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/570739/if-an-apple-is-bad-and-there-are-5-apples-of-the-same-type-of-the-apple-mention)

I have asked the question and before I received any answers to the question, the question was closed by a person based on his wish and will. My question does fall dutifully under the topic. One, based on his wish and will, cannot close another's question. **one's wish and will is not present in the agreement between me and english.Stackexchange.com.** He has also asked me, in his private feedback, to "consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better". He has also asked me to include my research, that he has claimed, that I have done. **The question that I have asked is fair, right and complete.** **I do not need to include anything that does not fall under the said agreement.**

### He has sent this as private feedback

> "Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers.
> Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

### Closed 1 hour ago.

Here by using the word "better" he has commented the degree of my post against the said agreement, again reflecting his actions is based on his wish and will. ****My contractual agreement with english.stackexchange.com is frustrated because of his action**. **As of now, I want my question to be allowed to be answered. I need the answers urgently.****

### When I click "Ask Question" I get this message

> "You have reached your question limit
> It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon!
>
> You've asked 2 questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking questions entirely."

==========================================

Here, in this message, I have been told that I am might ultimately be blocked from asking questions. **This is wrong, wrongful, bad and unreasonable. None of my questions, I have asked so far breaks any rules of english.stackexchange.com.**

Moving forward, as of now, I want my question to be opened for receiving answers.

Regards
joee

Comment: It’s worth reading the take of a real-life, honest-to-goodness professor of linguistics (with 40 years experience) on [“which is correct?”-type questions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15085/55623), such as your apple one.

Comment: I'm sure you are aware that it's rude to shout, so I decreased the size of the font in bold. It's also rude to demand answers. `I need the answers urgently.`

Comment: Closing based on 'being a rant' does not appear on the menu...@MichaelHarvey You just have 1 person out of thousands that thinks it is a rant, that's all. Comments can not be DVed.

Comment: @JJJ the OP has been a member for only 29 days, and has asked one question (if they have deleted others, I cannot tell). It's impossible that they are prevented from posting new questions by the system as your proposal suggests. This is not a duplicate of [Reached Question Limit](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11031/reached-question-limit) The OP is specifically complaining about a single question of theirs that was closed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not sure that's true. The quote in this question seems to be the question-block message. The rate limit can kick in after as few as two poorly received questions which seems to be the case here. Note that there may be (self-)deleted questions which don't show up on the user's profile.

Comment: OMG @JJJ two low quality questions and a user is blocked. That's awful! How is the OP supposed to overcome that hurdle? Two low-quality/off-topic questions? Really, that few?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yea I think it happens when both questions are poorly received without upvotes. Just a few upvotes seem to keep it at bay, at least in my experience. I don't know how the algorithm works precisely (that's an SE secret). I also know it doesn't kick in (as easily) if you've had positively received questions on other sites in the network.

Comment: @JJJ score: -2 on the deleted question and -4 on the non-deleted question, which  is extremely similar to the older question. Reading the history of "events", it seems that the four downvotes occurred 12 hours ago, but the OP was already blocked before the downvotes had been cast. How is it possible that a user is blocked because of one self-deleted question and another that was closed by the community? It seems awfully unfair.

Comment: @joee How many posts have you deleted in the past? Do you have other accounts on Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Mari-LouA He has an account on ELL. He asked a version of his “apple” question there; it was also closed and downvoted. He asked a new, unrelated question on ELL this morning.

Answer (score 8):

Your questions have not been “wrongfully closed”. Please read:

- Our [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour).
- Our Help Center's guidance on [why some questions are closed](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).
- Our Help Center's guidance on [how to ask questions here](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
- Our Help Center's guidance on [the sorts of questions you should avoid asking here](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).
- The Stack Exchange network's [theory of moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/).
- The Stack Exchange network's [frequently asked questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).
- [What you can do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997)

I can see that you are new both to the Stack Exchange question-and-answer network in general and to our site for English experts. This probably accounts for why you're misunderstood how things work here.

First off, not a single one of the several messages you have cited was ever sent to you by an actual human being, malicious or otherwise. Every single one of them is an automatic message provided by the software that runs things here, ones sent when certain patterns are detected by that software's algorithms.

However, [your most recent question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/570739) ***was*** closed by unpaid members of our community here, actual humans acting in concert to moderate the site. In this instance, three close votes, each from a different community member, sufficed to close your question. The same circumstances also apply to [your previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/569090).

I recommend that you step back and read up on how things work here via the links I have placed at the top of this post to help you.

***Your questions do not meet the quality standards*** that we have established for our site. They were closed because of this. Contrary to your assertion, they are not well-formed questions at all, because you have not presented any research whatsoever. Most questions here of the form "Which one is right, A or B?" will be quickly closed by the community with no more thought than you put into it while typing it. These are personal proofreading requests that will never help future visitors to our site looking for expert answers to their own questions.

You seem to be someone learning English. Probably our site for English linguists and English-language experts and enthusiasts is not well-suited to your needs. As the guidance given you suggests, you may be better served by our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com). But they, too, have formal  research requirements, and so as currently written your questions would probably be closed just as quickly there as well. ***You have to show some real effort here***, and you have failed to do this.

Lastly, your legalistic verbiage about your "contract" is not a matter which  our community of unpaid volunteers can possibly answer. Once you start rattling the chains of righteous umbrage in a lawyerly contractual fashion as you have done here, you have moved far beyond any area that can be addressed by the community of unpaid volunteers. You ***will not and cannot*** receive legally binding responses from our community of unpaid volunteers here. That can come only from the company proper.

Instead you must take your "grievance", such as it is, to actual paid employees who are legally allowed to speak for the company under guidance of their general counsel, (highly) paid attorneys versed in the matters of contact law that you allege the company to be in violation of.

To initiate that communication, use the [Contact Us](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of every page here. You may also deliver them a written letter by post to their corporate headquarters if you prefer.

Comment: Looks like he knows about ELL and even tried there first, [with similar results](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/289005/10446).

Comment: @DanBron Curious how ***“JUST GIMME DA @#^$!#%& CODEZ!”*** demands upon our network manage to show up on every one of its sites, innit?

Comment: It is astounding. And infuriating.

Comment: @tchrist - a pedant writes: isn't it `teh codez`?